# Issue in simpledateformat in java

Tags: java

I want to get date in the format of MMyyyy and here is my code

```
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMyyyy");
      String d="02-2014";
      Date d1=sdf.parse(d);
      System.out.println("the date is:" +d1);
```

As my string is not in a given format it should throw an exception but it is giving an output like

**the date is:Sat Jun 01 00:00:00 IST 2272**

Help me out

Comment: Call `sdf.setLenient(false)`  before using it .

Comment: Its Working Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

add `sdf.setLenient(false);` and you get an exception

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMyyyy");
sdf.setLenient(false);
String d="02-2014";
Date d1=sdf.parse(d);
System.out.println("the date is:" +d1);
```

For more informations read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean))

Comment: Its Working Thanks a lot